# partial view login on home page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

This question has been asked many times but I don't think the way I need it.

I'm trying to implement a login form on the home page but this form is located in a section that pops up, like you have on this site: http://myanimelist.net.

I've created a **partial view** for my login form:

```
@model ArtWebShop.Models.customers

@section Validation {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<section id="login">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginValidate", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email) 

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password)

            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
        </fieldset>
    }

</section>
```

This is shown on the **home page (index.cshtml)**:

```
<section class="shown">
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</section>
```

The partial view is shown correctly.
But now comes the part that doesn't work.

When you press login if you haven't filled in the fields, the validation is done in my LoginController as it should but I can't seem the send the errors to my home page view when I redirect.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginValidate(string redirect)
    {
        if (_unitOfWork.CustomersRepository.CostumerIsValid(Request.Form["email"], Request.Form["password"]))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(redirect) || String.Compare(redirect, "none", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                if (redirect != null) Response.Redirect(redirect, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("email", "You entered an incorrect email address");
        ModelState.AddModelError("password", "You entered an invalid password");

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }
```

That's my loginValidation. Since nothing is filled in the errors are added to the ModelState and then it redirects to the home page. This however doesn't shows me the errors.I'm guessing it's exactly because I redirect but how can I solve this?

Comment: How do you open the login popup? Do you want to have the same behaviour as on the link you provided? Why closing the popup if you have errors? Isn't it better a behaviour like here: http://www.minidevils.de/minibreakdown/#

Comment: That is indeed an even better example. I used that link I provided in my OP to show what I meant with login pop-up in case it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TempDataDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to store the *ModelStateDictionary* between redirects.

> **TempDataDictionary Class**
>   Represents a set of data that persists only from one request to the next.

In your **LoginValidate** action you would store the *ModelState* like so:

```
public ActionResult LoginValidate(string redirect)
{
    /* Your other code here (omitted for better readability) */

    ModelState.AddModelError("email", "You entered an incorrect email address");
    ModelState.AddModelError("password", "You entered an invalid password");

    // Add the ModelState dictionary to TempData here.
    TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;

    return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
}
```

And in your **HomeController**, **Index** action you would check if the *TempData* has a *ModelState*:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var modelState = TempData["ModelState"] as ModelStateDictionary;
    if (modelState != null)
    {
        ModelState.Merge(modelState);
    }

    return View();
}
```

You could make this a little bit cleaner by using custom action filters; see [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg), number 13.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed, thanks! But is there a way to pass the error messages with the redirect like you can do with a view (e.g. return view("index", model)? Or am I just thinking of making it too complex and not look for other ways. It's just that I want to keep it as clean as possible and not mix too much different techniques and patterns.

Comment: @reaper_unique You probably can, but I don't think that will be cleaner. I would actually rather go with doing an ajax login instead and act according to the result from the server (may it be an login ok and redirect or the errors), but this answer is just one way of solving it =)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using jQueryUI Dialogs and AjaxForms. Please check this demo: http://demo.ricardocovo.com/EditDialogsAndFormRazor/Cars. 
You can implement a similar behaviour for your login form as for the Edit functionality in the link provided. You'll find the idea explained here: http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/

Comment: That is something I will do after I made sure the server validation works.

Comment: You can add the server validation in the action method that
we'll be called asynchronously when the the partial view form will be submited.